# Open param doesn't work (InlineDatePicker) - material ui

Tags: material-ui

```
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider, InlineDatePicker } from 'material-ui-pickers'
    
    
<InlineDatePicker
  shouldDisableDate={day => isSameDay(day, new Date())}
  onlyCalendar
  open={isOpen}
  minDate={addYears(new Date(), -18)}
  value={begin}
  renderDay={renderDay}
  onClose={() => {
     onChange([begin, end].sort())
       if (onClose) onClose()
     }}
   onClear={() => {
   setBegin(undefined)
   setEnd(undefined)
   setHover(undefined)
      onChange([])
   }}
   ref={picker}
   labelFunc={(date, invalid) =>
     labelFunc
     ? labelFunc([begin, end].sort(), invalid)
     : date && begin && end
      ? `${formatDate(begin)} - ${formatDate(end)}`
      : emptyLabel || ''
      }
  {...props}
/>
```

I try to open date picker by using `open` parameter , but it doesn't work, what do I do wrong ? Version is : `"material-ui-pickers": "^2.2.4"`. Also I pass this param to prevent showing input text field `TextFieldComponent={() => null}`

Answer (score 0):

```
const picker = useRef()

const onClick = e => {
 return picker.current.open(e)
}

.....
<InlinePicker>
 ref={picker}
</InlinePicker /
```

This will be working